# Intel Wifi card module not visible in linux menuconfig

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I've gotten myself into a pickle it seems. I just got the latest gentoo kernel (3.7.10), and it seems that they didn't include my wireless lan driver in the menuconfig (or it depends on another option to become visible or something). Anyway, here is what I know:

- The driver/firmware I need is `ipw2200`
- Doing a search in menuconfig (with '/') for "ipw2200" reveals that it is available:

  ```
  Symbol: IPW2200 [=n]
  Type  : tristate
  Prompt: Intel PRO/Wireless 2200BG and 2915ABG Network Connection
    Defined at drivers/net/wireless/ipw2x00/Kconfig:66
    Depends on: NETDEVICES [=y] && WLAN [=y] && PCI [=y] && CFG80211 [=y] && CFG80211_WEXT [=n]
    Location:
      -> Device Drivers
        -> Network device support (NETDEVICES [=y])
          -> Wireless LAN (WLAN [=y])
            -> Intel PRO/Wireless 2200BG and 2915ABG Network Connection (IPW2200 [=n])
  ```
- I can't find it there.

Is there any way I can manually set the variable to [=m] in a config file or something? Any help would be greatly appreciated!!! Thank you!

Comment: That's a SuperUser question. Someone should move it there. In any case, please *also* post the dependencies. It seems some of them are not satisfied, and this is why you can't select this option. Do not try to set it manually, or stuff will BREAK.

Comment: Sorry man, should I ask on there, or wait for a mod o move it? Also, all the dependencies were satisfied, but ill post them on here for reassurance. Thank you.

Comment: There are only three dependencies in Kconfig, but why do you have the last dependency as *"CFG80211_WEXT [=n]"*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are configuring your own kernel, check that the dependencies are set right. They are probably scattered all over `make menuconfig`. Perhaps `make xconfig` (or some of the other GUIish configuraton options) is nicer to handle here.

A **very dirty** way out is just editing the `.config` file, looking for `CONFIG_NETDEVICES` and the others, and edit them to match what the dependency line you cite says. After that, run `make oldconfig` (that should clean up any tangles you created; note carefully what it asks you and compare original/edited/fixed files afterwards to make sure, might also check with `make menuconfig`).

If it breaks, you get to keep both pieces. Good luck!

Comment: The superuser way of saying "Thanks" is to just accept and upvote the answer. And you are wellcome.